# Apps Scirpt and regex. How?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using .indexOf() to parse an array in a separate sheet via url and find a string in a header to return a numerical value or -1. Issue is I need to find the string match that is non case sensitive. ie var targetEmail = targetHeader.indexOf("Email"); would need to match "email", "user email", User email", etc. Normally I would use a regex but can't find a way to do this in Apps Script. Please any help would be very much appreciated.

sample code below:

```
var userHeader = USER.getRange(1, 1, 1, USER.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var targetHeader = importSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, importSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();


 var targetEmail = targetHeader.indexOf("Email");
 if(targetEmail == -1)
    ui.alert("Can not find Email column. Please rename column in source sheet.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Javascript RegExp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp),  you can use the following

```
let targetEmail = targetHeader.findIndex(h => /email/gi.test(h));
if(targetEmail == -1) 
  ui.alert("Can not find Email column. Please rename column in source sheet.");
```

Note: `findIndex`, `let` and the function shorthand will only work if your script is using the new V8 runtime.

I personally prefer to name the column I want using Google Sheets named ranges, and then use `getNamedRanges()`, so I'll be able to find the column number by its range name, regardless of the column heading text. If columns are inserted or deleted, the named range still points to the column you're looking for.

Comment: I believe OP wants to find the column number.

Comment: @ADW, OP was also asking about how to use RegExp in Apps Script. But thanks, I've updated my code to answer their question more directly.

Answer (score -1):

You could solve for this by

(1) joining the array into a string

`targetHeader.join()`

(2) and then changing the string to lowercase

`toLowerCase()`

and then looking for "email" (lower case).

```
  var targetHeader = importSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, importSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  targetHeader = targetHeader.join().toLowerCase();
  var targetEmail = targetHeader.indexOf('email');
```

---

### Edit:

To find the column number with the word 'email' in it:

```
  var importSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet101');
  var targetHeader = importSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, importSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var flag = false;
  for (var c = 0; c < targetHeader.length; c++) {
    var cellValue = targetHeader[c].toLowerCase();
    if (cellValue.indexOf('email') > -1) {
      flag = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!flag) {
    // ui alert that email not found
  } else {
    var columnWithEmalInHeader = c + 1;
    // column with value 'email' found. Column number is c+1
    // first time match of 'email' will pop-up here. All subsequent amounts will be ignored.
  }
```

Comment: Here's the issue. When my code finds a match for the text it returns the array position of where it found said string and then passes the numerical value to yet another function which then retrieves the data stored in said separate spreadsheet's corresponding column via retrieved numerical value.

If I use .join() I run the risk of encountering "User Email" which would increase the returned array position by +1 no? In doing so passing the incorrect value and retrieving the incorrect column.

Comment: You will need extra code to do that. See my edit above.

Comment: True this will work for this instance but will not scale gracefully. Thank you for your.  time and. insight. I have a lot of headers to search for ... I. was hoping to. find a way to use regex in AppsScript but Im not finding it.

Comment: indexOf(/someexpression/i); or some function im just missing...

Comment: var column={};targetHeader.forEach(function(e,l){column[e]=I}); then use column[header name] to find index